# How to enable automatic method suggestion in swift in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode6

i am learning swift programming language. Unlike objective-c , it does not have automatic method suggestion and variable replacement. Is there any trick or setting for automatic method suggestion in swift?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i know it's not possible yet, it's a beta and not implemented yet. Wait for the next release or report a bug to apple

Comment: @0x7ffff First let me know that where is check box? I know that you people want reward of any silly answer. If i will not satisfies with the answer then why should i mark check box up and one more important things that i know all the rules of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Rahul It's located just to the left of each answer. Marking answers is not a requirement. We only ask that you do this when the answer was correct and helped you solve your problem.

Comment: You could see if AppCode supports this, I wouldn't be suprised if it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to autocomplete, Swift does have autocomplete, but it's buggy and sometimes breaks. If it's not working, try deleting the derived data for your project and letting it re-index. The directory should be at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`